# Check if file does not exist or permission denied C

Tags: c, io

How do I check if a file does not exist or it exists but I do not have permission to read it?

I know I can use stuff like `perror()` or `strerror(errno)` to print messages, but if I want a check that I can handle like this, how do I do that:

```
if (not exist) {
    create file;
}
else if (no permission) {
    exit;
}
```

This is the code I am working on. I think `err` is always = -1 when the file does not exist or I do not have permission, so I don't know how to deal with it.

```
int fdPath, n, err;
   unsigned char buffer[4096];
   char *path;

   // get path
   path = argv[1];

   // get file descriptor from opening file
   fdPath = open(path, O_RDWR);

   err = read(fdPath, buffer, 4096); // read file in path
```

Comment: Try to open the file and check errno.  It will (non-portably) tell you the reason if there was a failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `open(2)` man page:

```
RETURN VALUE
   open(), openat(), and creat() return the new file descriptor,
   or -1 if an error occurred  (in
   which case, errno is set appropriately).
```

That tells you that if you want to find out the reason the system call has failed, you need to check the `errno` variable, which may be setting to something like `EACCESS` (permissioned denied) or `ENOENT` (no such file or directory), etc.

[This](https://github.com/skuhl/sys-prog-examples/blob/master/simple-examples/errno.c) looks like a reasonable example.

Answer (score 5):

Do not try to know *in advance* whether you can write to or read from a file -- you will have a race condition when the information changes between your check and your actual access. Do something like the following

```
int fd = open(path, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 00666);
if (fd < 0) exit(1);
```

If you must know the reason why you can't open or create the file, you need of course some more code that checks `errno`.

edit to clarify: `O_CREAT` will only attempt to create the file when it's not already there. But this check is done inside the operating system, so it is an atomic operation for your process (no other process can change the situation between trying to open the file and trying to create it).

Comment: Note that depending on your exact needs, adding the `O_EXCL` flag to `open` may also be useful -- if it is included the file will only be created if it does not already exist.

Comment: @JohnHascall no, that's wrong. `O_EXCL` with `O_CREAT` will *fail* if the file exists. `O_CREAT` alone will just open it (without creating it)

Comment: @JohnHascall "the file will only be created if it does not already exist." <- that's what `O_CREAT` *alone* does. `O_EXCL` will make `open()` *fail* if the file exists.

Comment: Ok, I think we are just saying the same thing (O_CREAT, file exists) => existing file opened; (O_CREAT, file doesn't exist) => new file created and opened; (O_CREAT|O_EXCL, file exists) => fails, nothing opened; (O_CREAT|O_EXCL, file doesn't exist) => new file created and opened

Answer (score 2):

On POSIX systems, you might use [access](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/access.html) to check that a file exists and/or is readable. However, be aware that if you first check the existence of a file, and later, if it does not exist, create it, there is a possible race (between checking existence & creating).